# DOMPDF <div> tag as header and footer

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf-generation, dompdf

I need to create a header and footer on a  tag using DOMPDF. How can I achieve this?

Assuming I have a header class like this one:

```
<div class='header'>
    <div>
        <img scr='image1.png' style="width:100px; height:150px" />
        <h1>This is header</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and a footer like this one

```
<div class='footer'>
    <div>
        <img scr='image1.png' style="width:100px; height:150px" />
        <h1>This is a footer. All rights reserved.</h1>
        <img src = image2.png style="width:100px; height:150px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create those `<div>` tags (class footer and class header) to create the DOMPDF header and footer.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: what? kindly elaborate your answer please ^^

Answer (score 1):

CSS :

```
position:fixed; 
top: 0; or bottom: 0;
```